# How does redis persist Nodejs sessions?

Tags: node.js, redis

I recently started using Redis on my Nodejs project. I use it to store my sessions.

```
const session = require("express-session")
const redis = require('redis')
let RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)

let redisClient
if(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL){
    // let redisURL = url.parse(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL);
    redisClient = redis.createClient(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL)
} else {
    redisClient = redis.createClient()
}

app.use(
        session({
            store: new RedisStore({
                client: redisClient
            }),
            secret: keys.session.secret,
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false
        })
    )
```

I am also using passport.js to handle user sessions:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        pool.query( `Select users.* where users.id = ${id} `, function(err, rows) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            else{
                done(err,rows[0]);    
            }
        });
    });
```

I was reading about how redis works and came upon this:

> When using a memory cache, your cookie only contains a session ID.
>   This removes the risk of private user information being exposed in the
>   cookie.

This means that at any given time the Nodejs server still has to store the session ID. When the browser sends the cookie back with user infromation and the encrypted secret Nodejs will have to find the session ID in the redis store and make sure that the information is correct.

Why is it that refreshing the Nodejs server not clear all the session ID from the database? Why do I not have to re-login everytime I refresh the server?

Comment: When you use redis as your session store, the sessions are stored there so as long as the redis database keeps running, your session data is still available.  The browser can refresh as many times as you want, the same cookie still persists in the browser and that cookie corresponds to a session that persists in redis.  Now, you you restart redis without saving a snapshot first, then since it's a memory-based storage, all sessions will be lost at that point.  Redis is a separate process from nodejs so you can also restart the nodejs server and not lose the redis store.

Comment: I was not no talking about refresihing browers. I was talking about refreshing Nodejs server. When the browser sends the request to Nodejs server, the Nodejs server first checks to see if it contains the sessionID. If it does, it queries the redis server for further info regarding that session ID. But when I restart the Nodejs server it should clear up the lookup key (sessionID), which should mean that the users will have to log back in and obtain a new sessionID. But this is not the case as I can restart the Nodejs server and do not have to login. Why is this the case?

Comment: Redis is a separate process.  If you restart your nodejs server, the redis store can still persist unless you also restart the redis server without first saving a snapshot.  This is one of the benefits/features of having it out of the nodejs process.

Comment: Does this mean Nodejs server stores nothing regarding the user sessions?

Comment: That depends upon your implementation, but if you're just using express-session and the redis connector, then nothing from the session is saved locally in nodejs - it's all in redis.  When a request arrives, redis is queried and the matching session data is retrieved for the duration of that request only.

Answer (score 2):

redis by default doesnt persist data to disk every time you write (normally just aof and no rdf). So if you restart redis, your data can be gone and your sessionId within your cookie doesn't exist anymore

you will need to [enable persistence within redis](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) or configure that in your [redistogo instance](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/redistogo).

if you want to flush all session information you can [FLUSHALL](https://redis.io/commands/flushall) on your redis instance. Best would be to [set the ttl (time to live)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis#ttl) so your sessions eventually get flushed by redis automatically after 30days or so